# Socket in python is not connecting for some devices

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding

I used python socket to connect to my other devices on a different network using port forwarding. It worked on some devices.

When I tried to connect with a device at a longer distance it shows a timeout error. Is it due to the long distance?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not due to network latency.  Socket timeout is usually on the order of tens of seconds, whereas network latency is rarely more than a second.  It's more likely you can't reach the destination server.

Try ping  to see if you can reach the destination server and how long a round trip takes (last column).

```
% ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.164.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.164.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=300.335 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.164.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=334.197 ms
```

If it really is taking too long, you can set your socket's timeout

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# set timeout to 60 seconds
s.settimeout(60)
```